# Contenteditable div onpaste, it the adding multiple \n

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using a contenteditable div and while pasting any text with line breaks. it is adding multiple \n. Please refer below code and suggest a solution:

**Sample Text Below**:

Hi Sir,

This is for the testing Purpose only.
Username: <>
Password: <>

Best,
DEMO USER

**Current Output in innerText**:

Hi Sir,\n\n\n\n\n\nThis is for the testing Purpose only.\nUsername: <>\nPassword: <>\n\n\n\n\nBest,\nDEMO USER

**Expected Output in innerText**:

Hi Sir,\nThis is for the testing Purpose only.\nUsername: <>\nPassword: <>\nBest,\nDEMO USER

Comment: Please provide the code for your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.